# Gulp.js: Reload altered php/html pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, livereload, gulp

I have a basic gulp.js setup running in my wordpress environment. Everything works how I would like except for the way I am reloading my changed .php files. I have it set up like this:

```
gulp.task('php', function(){
    gulp.src('../*.php').pipe(livereload(server));
});

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        server.listen(35729, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            };
            gulp.watch('styl/src/*.scss', ['styl']);
            gulp.watch('js/src/*.js', ['js']);
            gulp.watch('../*.php', ['php']);
        });
    });
```

I am essentially just having it reload the page whenever any php file is saved, but whenever I save one, it will automatically refresh every php page, whether I have it open, whether it was saved, or anything else:

```
[gulp] footer.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/footer.php ...
[gulp] front-page.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/front-page.php ...
[gulp] functions.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/functions.php ...
[gulp] header.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/header.php ...
[gulp] index.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/index.php ...
[gulp] social-media.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/social-media.php ...
[gulp] template-contact.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/template-contact.php ...
[gulp] template-interior.php was reloaded.
... Reload /Users/KBD/sites/vi/cnt/themes/vi/template-interior.php ...
```

Is there a way I can have it only livereload the page that was saved? This seems to be the only thing I can't get to work how I want with gulp; I am loving how much faster it runs than grunt, though.

EDIT: @SirTophamHatt

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    server.listen(35729, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err)
        };
        gulp.watch('styl/src/*.scss', ['styl']);
        gulp.watch('js/src/*.js', ['js']);
        gulp.watch('js/src/*.coffee', ['coffee']);
        gulp.src('../*.php').pipe(watch()).pipe(livereload(server));

    });
});
```

Comment: I'm interested in seeing your complete gulp configuration as I'm trying to use gulp to run a php server and livereload when I change php/phtml, css, and js files.

Comment: I've posted my watch task above, because the whole file seemed like a lot to post, but I can find a way to post more if you would like!

Comment: Could you please post it on jsfiddle or plunkr? It would be a huge help for me getting livereload to work with PHP.

Comment: Here ya go. Let me know if you have any questions.

http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/uzeJd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`gulp-watch` plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch) instead.  It's much better for watching individual files, and only passing those through to your results.  Plus, it can watch for *new* files as well, if you use `watch({glob: ['files']}).pipe(...)` instead of `gulp.src(['files']).pipe(watch()).pipe(...)`.

An alternative is to use [`gulp-newer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-newer/) or [`gulp-changed`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-changed/), which both use timestamps to determine if a file has changed or not.  I haven't personally used either, but `gulp-newer` appears to have a little more functionality.  Neither will be able to detect new files, however.

Answer (score 0):

Refs [here](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#sample-usages), You could simply `watch` them:

```
gulp.watch('../*.php').on('change', function(file) {
    livereload(server).changed(file.path);
});
```

Furthermore, currently [`gulp-livereload`](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#livereloadparam) supports automatic creating of an instance of `tiny-lr` server. Thus you don't require `tiny-lr` explicitly:

```
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('task foo', function() {
    gulp.src('foo').pipe(...).pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('foo', ['task foo'])
    gulp.watch('bar').on('change', function(file) {
        livereload().changed(file.path);
    });
});
```

Comment: small correction to above code: it's `changed(file.path)` not `change(file.path)`

Comment: It's: livereload.changed(file.path);   NOT: livereload().changed(file.path);